# Getting Error when converting to datetime :Date Column + Time Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is my sql query, Inner query returning the value but outer query returning error:
"**Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type. "**

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
     Convert(SMALLDATETIME, Convert(VARCHAR(30), Convert(DATE, Event_Date, 101)) + 
     Convert(VARCHAR(30), ' ') + Convert(VARCHAR(30), Convert(TIME, Event_Time)), 101)
        ,[Event_Date]
        ,Location
        ,Street
        ,City
        ,[State]
        ,Country
        ,ZipCode
        ,[Subject]
        ,[Detail]
        ,[LeadInstructor]
        ,[CoInstructor]
    FROM [Temp_EVT_EVENT]
    ) x
```

Comment: What **datatype** is `Event_Date` in your database?

Comment: It is of varchar type.I want to convert my value to DateTime so that i can insert it into another table

Comment: Post your inner query result

Comment: 2015-01-08 08:00:00 as event_Date

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If you need to store a date - store it as `DATE` or `DATETIME` - but certainly ***not*** as a `varchar` !!

Comment: Convert(SMALLDATETIME, Convert(VARCHAR(30), Convert(DATE, Event_Date, 101)) + 
     Convert(VARCHAR(30), ' ') + Convert(VARCHAR(30), Convert(TIME, Event_Time)), 101) - what is your expected answer for the query.

Comment: Please tell how we can do this is column is of date for date and for time it it time type

Comment: Verra:result will be of datetime type.so that i can insert it into small datetime type column

Comment: 2015-01-08 08:00:00.0000000 - Is this is what you get in inner query or 2015-01-08 08:00:00 itself.

Comment: ya it is like this 2015-01-08 08:00:00.0000000

Comment: check the answer. and update the result you get.

Comment: post the error you get

Comment: Also, I updated the answer. Recheck it

Comment: If it works mark the answer. Then only it can help some one else.

Comment: again getting same error ...same error:"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."
I don't understand why it is so if my error query resulting correct answer with column as datetime then why is it throwing error in outer query.

Comment: Sorry ,You were right @Verra ,I got my answer .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMALLDATE can accept time value upto 18:00:00. But you used TIME format 18:00:00.000000 that is why it show error. Check the query and update the status.

First run this query separately:

```
  SELECT 
     Convert(SMALLDATETIME, Convert(VARCHAR(30), Convert(DATE, CAST('2014-11-14' AS DATETIME), 101)) + 
     Convert(VARCHAR(30), ' ') + Convert(VARCHAR(30), CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST('18:13:04' AS DATETIME), 108)), 101) AS column1
```

if you get the answer. '2014-11-14 18:13:00'

Then try to run:

```
 SELECT 
         Convert(SMALLDATETIME, Convert(VARCHAR(30), Convert(DATE, CAST(Event_Date AS DATETIME), 101)) + 
         Convert(VARCHAR(30), ' ') + Convert(VARCHAR(30), CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(Event_Time AS DATETIME), 108)), 101) AS column1 FROM Temp_EVT_EVENT
```

if you get the answer correctly. Then Run:

```
 SELECT x.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
     Convert(SMALLDATETIME, Convert(VARCHAR(30), Convert(DATE, CAST(Event_Date AS DATETIME), 101)) + 
     Convert(VARCHAR(30), ' ') + Convert(VARCHAR(30), CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(Event_Time AS DATETIME), 108)), 101) AS column1
        ,[Event_Date]
        ,Location
        ,Street
        ,City
        ,[State]
        ,Country
        ,ZipCode
        ,[Subject]
        ,[Detail]
        ,[LeadInstructor]
        ,[CoInstructor]
    FROM [Temp_EVT_EVENT]
    ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on your Event_Date format, look here: [Date Formats](http://sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/sqlserverstringtodate/)

It seems that the correct format is 120, and not 101.

So:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
     Convert(SMALLDATETIME, Convert(VARCHAR(30), Convert(DATE, Event_Date, 120)) + 
     Convert(VARCHAR(30), ' ') + Convert(VARCHAR(30), Convert(TIME, Event_Time)), 120)
        ,[Event_Date]
        ,Location
        ,Street
        ,City
        ,[State]
        ,Country
        ,ZipCode
        ,[Subject]
        ,[Detail]
        ,[LeadInstructor]
        ,[CoInstructor]
    FROM [Temp_EVT_EVENT]
    ) x
```